# Use Magento-Block in another block

Tags: php, magento, random, block

I'm using a Magento custom Block like this:

```
{{.... template="page/mytemplate.phtml" variable="100" ....}}
```

I want to change the value "100" to a random number every time the block will get executed. I tried to implement another Block in this one. Like:

```
{{...  template="page/mytemplate.phtml" variable="{{ ...  ANOTHER BLOCK HERE  ...}}" ...}}
```

But it breaks the execution of the first block. So does anyone know a good solution for this?

Comment: I think you have set same name for both blocks, Please try with different block names, and check.

Comment: @user247217 where should i specify the name of the block? I just add a file in the templates/pages folder and use it from there....

Comment: like below
{{.... template="page/mytemplate.phtml" variable="100" name="yourblockname1"}} and {{.... template="page/mytemplate.phtml" variable="100" name="yourblockname2"}}

Comment: also you will set same template for both so try to use different or add if conditions

Comment: @user247217 i tryed it exctly like this: {{block type="folio/folio" template="folio/list.phtml" showdescription="1"  foliotheme="masonryproject" lightbox="1" showpostbtn="0" itemsperpage="300" viewimagetxt="Bild anzeigen" filteralltext="Alle"  showdate="0" name="galerie" test='{{block type="core/template" template="beins/beins_rnd.phtml" name="rnd"}}'}}  it outputs the first block and breaks after the second one. The rest of code would be outputted like plain text. I can see the last chars after the second block: "'}} "

Comment: are you trying with different templates?

Comment: magento does not allow like you have set above

Comment: Yes. One templates genereates a portfolio and the other (bein_rnd.phtml) just outputs a random number. I try to use that random number in a variable of the first block.

Comment: Yes. And thats why im searching for a solution sir :)

Comment: Why not just generate a random value within your block? i.e. create a custom block (folio/random) that generates a random number in a function that your template calls?

Comment: @DouglasRadburn thats what im doing actually. But i cant insert a second block in another one. Thats my problem. It wont work either it have another name and template path / file